# AWS initial instance drains when auto-scaling

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, autoscaling

I'm trying to configure an AWS autoscaling setup (This is the first time I'm trying it). So far I have created an alarm to add a new instance when

- CPU usage is more than 25%
- Period 1
- Data points 1 out of 1

Then I ren a JMeter script to generate a load to the machine. When the load is high, the alarm will go to **in-Alarm** state ( Approximate CPU usage is around 60% and memory 50% ).
My problem is,

Before the second instance is up and healthy, both my instances start draining. I expected something like this if the CPU usage is 100% or memory is 100%. When I stop the Jmeter script, both the instances will become healthy in a few minutes.

Then if I execute the same load again ( when both instances are up ), the system will run smoothly and even it will add the 3rd instance.

My problem is, what could be the reason for the draining of the working instance when the CPU usage is NOT 100%?

any idea?

Comment: How long is the period of time for the alarm?

Comment: What do you mean by "both my instances start draining" and "draining of the working instance"? Also, you say "both the instances will become healthy" -- are you saying that some instances became _unhealthy_? Feel free to edit your question to clarify details.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein
What I ment is, There is a single instance when I start the load. then I want AWS to add multiple instances. But when the second instance is adding, the initial one will be draining and the second one also draining. Basically, application is down and can't serve any of the requests.

Comment: @hephalump The period time is 1 min and we have given an interval of 300s for the new instance to be healthy.

Comment: Why are the instances 'draining'? Is it because Auto Scaling is wanting to scale-in and remove the instances? I still don't understand what you mean by "when the second instance is adding... the second one also draining". What do you mean by "draining"?

Comment: I meant is stopping. I start the test with instance 1, then it's CPU usage goes passing 25% then the alarm triggers,  and 2nd instance starts. After a few minuts, before the second instance gets healthy - 1nstance will stop, then the second one will stop too. I'm getting the 503 response code too ( for the requests I sent). When I stop the load, within few minutes, both the instances will be healthy. sorry if it's not clear enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The AutoScaling Group will show you the reason it decides to terminate instances in the Activity History (if you're still using the old console you have to press the dropdown arrow on the left side of the 'terminate' message).

I assume when you say its draining, you mean that AutoScaling is deregistering it from the load balancer, and is getting ready to terminate it.  What I assume is happening is that the instance is failing ELB healthchecks, which the ASG sees and then marks the instance as unhealthy and terminates it.  If you have an Application Load Balancer it will usually show the reason for healthcheck failures if you hove over the (i) next to the instance when you look at the target group's Instances tab

In general, the only reason that an ASG would terminate an instance is:

1. A manual change or scale in alarm caused the desired to go down
2. A healthcheck failure (EC2, or ELB if ELB healthchecks are enabled on the ASG)
3. Some sort of administrative task like AZ reballancing

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. Since I'm really new to this didn't have a clear picture on what's happening. Will check it and update you.

Comment: The reason was the health check. The time gap 5s was not enough. Thank you !!